# .NET Core 6 upload file to wwwroot/images fails sometimes and uploads half images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to upload files from a website to my wwwroot/images directory but sometimes only half the image get uploaded and it doesnt seem to work with .png files, here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile userfile)
        {
            MgvaKrantransportContext DBContext = new MgvaKrantransportContext();

            try
            {
                Image image = new Image() { Filepath = "images/" + userfile.FileName, Filename = userfile.FileName };

                DBContext.Add(image);
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.message = ex.Message;
            }


            try
            {
                string filename = userfile.FileName;
                filename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                string uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images", filename);

                var stream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                userfile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                ViewBag.message = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.message = ex.Message;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And here is the form in the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Management", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h2>Upload File</h2>
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Thanks beforehand!
Best regards Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `CopyToAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.copytoasync) returns a `Task` which must be `await`ed for the copy to succeed. Your code is currently closing the destination stream before the copy completes.

Either change your code to use [the synchronous `CopyTo` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.copyto), or make your action method `async` and `await` the task.

You'll also want to remove any directory information from the `FileName` before saving the name to the database - you've done it when you construct the physical path, but not for the `Image` entity.

And add `await using` to the `DbContext` and `FileStream` instances to ensure they are always disposed of properly.

There's no point storing values in the `ViewBag` if you're going to return a redirection; those values will always be lost. You could use `TempData` instead, which would store the messages in the session.

And `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is not really the best way to get the root path of the application. Instead, inject [the `IWebHostEnvironment` service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment) and use its `WebRootPath` property to find the physical path of the `wwwroot` folder.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile userfile)
{
    await using MgvaKrantransportContext DBContext = new MgvaKrantransportContext();
    try
    {
        string filename = userfile.FileName;
        filename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        
        Image image = new() 
        { 
            Filepath = "images/" + filename, 
            Filename = filename 
        };

        await DBContext.AddAsync(image);
        await DBContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        string uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(WebHost.WebRootPath, "images", filename);

        await using var stream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Create);
        await userfile.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log the error somewhere
    }
    
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, the thing I am curious about is the WebHost.WebRootPath, I used it in .net core 3 but now its not really the same thing, same with the IConfiguration. Should I still use it?

Comment: As far as I can see, `IWebHostEnvironment` hasn't changed since .NET Core 3.x; it's still the proper way to access the physical path for the content files.