# upload file to wwwroot with ajax dot net 6 core

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

everyone!

I want to upload file to wwwroot/upload_files using ajax and .net For now I've successfully implemented the backend which is uploading file to location. But it is not working with ajax or maybe I'm not using the correct appoarch.

here is my view index.cshtml

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" />                                                

<input type="button"id="upload" value="Upload" />
```

ajax

```
        $("#upload").click(function (evt) {

            var fileUpload = $("#files");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FilesController/UploadFile", //'https://localhost:7032/api/Files/UploadFile' and /Web/wwwroot/upload_files - but nothing works
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                },

                error: function () {

                    alert("There was error uploading files!");

                }

            });

        });
```

controller

```
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile files)
        {
            if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
                return BadRequest("file not selected");

          
            string rootPath = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;

          
            string completePath = "";
            if (rootPath.Contains("RCSolution"))
            {
                // split the path till 
                completePath = rootPath.Substring(0, rootPath.IndexOf("Web"));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(completePath);
            string fullPath = completePath + "Web/wwwroot/upload_files/" + files.FileName;

            //string path = Path.Combine(fullPath);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await files.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }


            //return RedirectToAction("Files");
            return Ok(files.FileName + " uploaded successfully " + "file location is " + fullPath);
        }
```

which is work fine as shown in this image

https://app.usebubbles.com/6D4FKyiLE1G6MMxCLY61t5/correct-backend

[image]

other apporach use from internet which does not works

[https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages#:~:text=Step%20to%20upload%20file%20in,a%20file%20on%20the%20server](https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages#:%7E:text=Step%20to%20upload%20file%20in,a%20file%20on%20the%20server).

[.NET Core 6 upload file to wwwroot/images fails sometimes and uploads half images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882033/net-core-6-upload-file-to-wwwroot-images-fails-sometimes-and-uploads-half-image)

can anyone please help me how to deal with this issue?
thanks

Comment: what is stored in "data" variable of Ajax method?

Comment: you data that you are sending should be a formdata and you need to append file in that formdata object
var data = new FormData();
data.append("files", $('#files')[0].files[0]);

Answer (score 1):

you data that you are sending should be a formdata and you need to append file in that formdata object

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("files", $('#files')[0].files[0]);
```

and you url should have format like "YourController/youraction"
so after creating data object your ajaxcall will be same

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FilesController/UploadFile",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);
            },

            error: function () {

                alert("There was error uploading files!");

            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, dear! 
I tried it already but not working, and also I implement your solution as well but not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

            target_url = api_url + "/api/Files/OnPostMyUploader";
            var files = $('#fileUpload').prop("files");
           
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("MyUploader", files[0]);

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: target_url,
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function (repo) {
                    if (repo.status == "success") {
                        alert("File : " + repo + " is uploaded successfully");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error occurs");
                }
            });
        });
```

this should work for me

thanks for all answers.